# When I clear the collection, it's clearing the contents of other collection as well why?

Tags: java

I have an array of ArrayList of the form ArrayList al, and I have a normal ArrayList al_1. I clear al_1 at some point in my code, but before clearing I put al_1 in al by using al.put(al_1). But When I clear al_1, even al is getting cleared. What might be the reason or my approach is wrong?

```
ArrayList<String> previousAction = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Double> arrayServerTimeInSecond = new ArrayList<Double>();
            ArrayList<String> uniqueActions = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> al = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                // create a row
                String[] data = itr.next().toString().split(",");
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowCount++);
                // write data into cells
                for (int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if (notHeader == true) {
                        if (j == 3) {
                            previousAction.add(data[j]);
                            actionCount++;
                        }
                        if (j == 16) {
                            if (previousAction.size() == 1) {
                                arrayServerTimeInSecond.add(Double.valueOf(data[j]));
                                uniqueActions.add(data[3]);
                            } else if (previousAction.size() > 1) {
                                if (previousAction.get(actionCount - 2).equals(data[3])) {
                                    arrayServerTimeInSecond.add(Double.valueOf(data[j]));
                                } else {
                                    al.add(uniqueActions.size()-1, arrayServerTimeInSecond);
                                    arrayServerTimeInSecond.removeAll(arrayServerTimeInSecond);
                                    arrayServerTimeInSecond.add(Double.valueOf(data[j]));
                                    uniqueActions.add(data[3]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cell = row.createCell((short) cellCount++);
                    cell.setCellValue(data[j]);
                }
                cellCount = 0;
                notHeader = true;
            }
```

and at 3rd line When i add a value to al_1, it is reflecting even on al, which will contain the data as in al_1? Please suggest me. Thank you

Comment: Please can you copy the entire class or method ?

Comment: I suspect your variable al_1 has the same reference of al

Answer (score 2):

`al.add(i++, al_1)` puts a reference to `al_1` in `al`.
If you later clear `al_1`, the member of `al` that contains that reference will contain an empty List.

In order to add a `List` identical to the original `al_1` to `al`, you should use :

```
al.add(new ArrayList(al_1));
```

or

```
al.add(someIndex,new ArrayList(al_1));
```

This would add a copy of `al_1` to `al`, so later changing `al_1` won't affect `al`.

Comment: Thank you so much@Eran, Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to clone an arrayList :

```
al.add(i++, al_1.clone())
```